# Masking react-native TextInput

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to figure out how to mask TextInput for a react-native app. I am completely new react-native, and I would prefer to not have to code a component for each iOS, Android and potentially Windows.
I see a bunch of existing modules for jQuery and regular React. Did not find one for react-native.

How does one go about addressing something like this? Do I attach a listener to the text input field, and rewrite the representation whenever the value of my field changes?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended-up hooking onChangeText and just using a roll-my-own function. Instead of onChangeText, we could also hook event from onChange. The arguments are different text vs event.

Comment: could you provide a gist or github repo with your solution please?